# How do I show line breaks in Django template without using the "linebreaksbr" template filter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

Let's say I have this:

```
first \n\n\n second
```

I want to display that on my page.  However, I don't want to use linebreaksbr filter because I'm using JQuery jeditable (edit in place).

When I click on my div, it'll turn it into a text are box.  In this case, it'll be `first<br><br><br> second`

I don't want that.  I want it to turn into a text area box with the line breaks already applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the preformatted (`<pre>`) tag.

Or you can replace the `<br>` with `\n` in jQuery while converting it to a textbox.